# Local DNS with wireless connections on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns

I using Ubuntu 12.04.1. I installed and configured Bind. I configured DNS to perform recourse queries, so I can use it for both for LAN and WAN.
Now, I want set my system to use the local DNS server, but the problem is that I use wifi connection and not the same one, so I can not configure wifi interfaces. Configuration of eth0 don't take effect...
By the way I use iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Mon Oct  1 21:14:26 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [60:7100]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [4664:2982035]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [58:13403]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct  1 21:14:26 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Mon Oct  1 21:14:26 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [31:2016]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:180]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct  1 21:14:26 2012
```

So, what can I do for all request to DNS from current computer will pass thrue local DNS?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your /etc/resolv.conf to start with

```
 nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

and you should be good to go.